# mi.anova warnings "assignment is deprecated"

Tags: r, warnings, r-mice

I am using mi.anova function from miceadds package. I am getting a depreciation message when I enter the code

```
SWManova <- mi.anova(mi.res=imputed_Data, "formula=outcome~person+age+sex+level_of_education", type=3)
```

with a warning as below:

```
> invalid formula "formula=zScoreSWMAdj~stratum.x+age+sex+level_of_education": assignment is deprecatedWarning: 
> invalid formula "formula=outcome~person+age+sex+level_of_education": assignment is deprecated
```

I am slightly unsure what is wrong, I realize it will be something simple but I just can't see it!

Comment: have you checked the syntax on the `?mi.anova` man page, and looked at the examples there for comparison?

Comment: my first guess is the opening quote should be like this `formula = "bla blah"`

Answer (score 0):

As Carl has said, quotations are meant to be mi.res=imputed_Data, formula="outcome~person+age+sex+level_of_education"

Ack, it's all ways something simple!